# Help! How to create a UI Tech Spec

Tags: user-interface, specifications

Crap. I've been tasked to create a technical spec for a UI I am developing. This is my first real developer job, and after looking at the tech spec for the backend of the project, I feel a little in over my head. I can do mockups and wireframes till the cows come home, but I'm not really sure how to put all this information together.

Does anyone know of a good resource or possibly a good example of a UI tech spec?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this is any help, but I like how the mozilla project is detailing ui specs on their wiki.
Example: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/UI/Designs/TouchScreen

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at the [General User Interface Specifications for OpenOffice](http://specs.openoffice.org/ui_in_general/index.html) for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

the wireframes/mockups are the most important thing to get right (they present functionality from *a users perspective*)

i have a blog article on creating wireframes, it describes a number of different tools you can use (from Word to Visio), that way you can chose whichever you feel most comfortable with: http://pm4web.blogspot.com/2008/10/wireframes-and-mockups-part-1.html

also try joel on softwares specification style: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000036.html

this is a very good basic spec style for beginners (its what i started with)

hope this helps

LM